# Automatic monthly updation of data in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have been designing a daily expense website where user can enter the data and it displays it along with the total expense of the user.
I want to change the total expense to monthly expense so that it shows **zero** at the starting of each month.
Here is my *html* file for displaying that part:

```
<h3 class='center'>Expenditure of this month: <span style="color:green;">{{ budget|floatformat:"-2" }}</span> dollars</h3>
```

I have tried `datetime` library of python in views to change it:

```
def app_view(request):
    bal_qs = [int(obj.cost) for obj in BudgetInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)]
    now = [i.lstrip("0") for i in datetime.now().strftime("%d")]
    budget=0
    if now[0]!='1':
        for obj in range(len(bal_qs)):
            budget=budget+bal_qs[obj]
    uzer_qs = BudgetInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-date_added')
    return render(request,'tasks_notes/index.html',{'budget':budget,'uzer':uzer_qs[0:5]})
```

But it's not changing the `budget` value monthly.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Add your models.py

Comment: Don't add to your `models.py` because you need this to be a monthly occurance, not an occurance on model change. I would add a management command with a cron command, or use something like Celery beat to update data every month...

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts I have been looking into `celery` and `cron` tabs, can you please explain how can I schedule the value of `budget` to be set as **zero** when a month overs?

Comment: Set a celery task to run on the first minute, of the first day of the first month...

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts got it, thank you for your help.